# MySQL error: cannot add foreign key constraint, but data types match

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create tables with foreign keys, but I keep getting error 1215 saying that it cannot add foreign key constraint. I double checked the datatypes and the REFERENCES part of the constraint, and that seems to be in order. I added ENGINE=InnoDB after reading through some of the MySQL documentation for the error, and that didn't solve it. I'm new to creating new databases, so I think I'm missing something. What can I add to resolve this error?

```
CREATE DATABASE cemc;
USE cemc;

CREATE TABLE CALENDAR(
    year            INT                 NOT NULL,
    term            VARCHAR(25)         NOT NULL,
    term_start      DATE                NOT NULL,
    term_end        date                NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT      CALENDAR_PK         PRIMARY KEY(year, term)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE COURSE(
    course_id       VARCHAR(6)          NOT NULL,
    skill           VARCHAR(25)         NOT NULL,
    level           VARCHAR(25)         NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT      COURSE_PK           PRIMARY KEY(course_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE TEACHER(
    teacher_id      VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    teacher_last    VARCHAR(25)         NOT NULL,
    teacher_first   VARCHAR(25)         NOT NULL,
    email1          VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    email2          VARCHAR(50)         NULL,
    phone1          INT                 NOT NULL,
    phone2          INT                 NULL,

    CONSTRAINT      TEACHER_PK          PRIMARY KEY(teacher_id)  
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE COURSEASSIGNMENT(
    course_id       VARCHAR(6)          NOT NULL,
    year            INT                 NOT NULL,
    term            VARCHAR(25)         NOT NULL,
    teacher_id      VARCHAR(50)         NULL,
    room            VARCHAR(3)          NULL,

    CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_PK          PRIMARY KEY(course_id, term),
    CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK1         FOREIGN KEY(term)
                                        REFERENCES CALENDAR(term),
    CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK2         FOREIGN KEY(course_id)
                                        REFERENCES COURSE(course_id),
    CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK3         FOREIGN KEY(year)
                                        REFERENCES CALENDAR(year),
    CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK4         FOREIGN KEY(teacher_id)
                                        REFERENCES TEACHER(teacher_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to reference Calendar. So far you are doing it correct with the data types. BUT  Calendar has a combined primary key. Thus you need to define the foreign key in one go instead of both separated, as mysql interprets these 2 as SEPARATE foreign keys instead of a combined one. And that leads to it not able to create the foreign key.

Thus you need to do:

```
CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_PK          PRIMARY KEY(course_id, term),
CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK1         FOREIGN KEY(year, term)
                                    REFERENCES CALENDAR(year, term),
CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK2         FOREIGN KEY(course_id)
                                    REFERENCES COURSE(course_id),
CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK4         FOREIGN KEY(teacher_id)
                                    REFERENCES TEACHER(teacher_id)
```

Comment: Can happen. Saw it a few times in the last few days. And that is one of the reasons why I tend to avoid combined keys where possible. Btw if an answer helps (solves a question) then pls set it as approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key must reference a primary key in the foreign table:

```
CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK1         FOREIGN KEY(term) REFERENCES CALENDAR(term)
```

And `term` is not the PK of table `Calendar`. The correct form should be:

```
CONSTRAINT      COURSEA_FK1         FOREIGN KEY(year,term) REFERENCES CALENDAR(year,term)
```